# What's the sort order of Java's Collections.sort(list, comparator)? small to big or big to small?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

Apparently, it's not documented or I missed it.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)'s the link to the documentation and below's the text as an image:

**EDIT**(17/5): I think too many confused this question to be a comparator question. It is not. The comparator compares between 2 elements. According to that comparison, the list sorted. **How? Ascending or Descending?**

I'll refine/simplify the question even further: If the comparator decides that element A is smaller than element B. **In the sorted list**, will element A be located at a lower index than element B?

[image]

Comment: It depends on how you have written `Comparator`?

Comment: Have you looked into the API of `Comparator`? It allows you to define your own sort order.

Comment: Please look at my edit from 15/7.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The sort order is always **ascending**, where the Comparator defines which items are larger than others.

From the documentation for [Collections.sort(List<T> list,
            Comparator<? super T> c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29):

> Sorts the specified list according to the order induced by the specified comparator.

From the documentation for [Comparator.compare(T,T)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29):

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Comment: Why do you think the sorted list is ascending?

Comment: Observation. After calling the method, the list is arranged from the smallest to the largest members, according to the definition provided by the comparator. Before observation, I would have guessed ascending order for parallelism with sibling method Collections.sort(List<T>), which *is* explicitly documented to be ascending order. The documentation for the method you're using would be improved by explicitly mentioning ascending order, just like its sibling.

Answer (score 21):

You (or rather, your comparator) decides.

- If your `Comparator`'s `compare(T o1, T o2)` return a negative when `o1` is less than `o2`, you get ascending order ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/GTqMub)).
- If your `Comparator`'s `compare(T o1, T o2)` return a negative when `o1` is greater than `o2`, you get descending order ([demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/RNG41K)).

Another way of saying the same thing would be that `sort` assumes that the comparator orders the two items passed into it from smaller (`o1`) to greater (`o2`), and produces an ascending sort consistent with that ordering.

Comment: Another way to look at this, more consistent with the Comparator contract, is that the Comparator defines which items are less-than, equal-to, or greater than others.

Comment: Shouldn't the second sentence be `return a positive when o1 is less than o2`? Otherwise it would sort the same way as in the first sentence.

Comment: @nif You're right, I should have "inverted" one part of the condition, not both. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the sorted list is ascending?

Comment: @kilaka It is always ascending in relation to the comparator: if your comparator is inverted, and it says "less than" when in fact it's greater than, then the output is in descending order.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation of `Comparator.compareTo(o1, o2)` method says

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer,
>   zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal
>   to, or greater than the second.

So if you want to sort from natural ordering , that is small to big, then you should write the implementation as defined in the documentation

```
public int compareTo(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
     int v1 = (o1);
     int v2 = (o2);
     if(v1 == v2) {
        return 0;
     }
     if(v1 < v2) {
        return -1; //return negative integer if first argument is less than second
     }
     return 1;
}
```

If you want the sorting to be in reverse order, that is big to small

```
public int compareTo(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
     int v1 = (o1);
     int v2 = (o2);
     if(v1 == v2) {
        return 0;
     }
     if(v1 < v2) {
        return 1;  //do the other way
     }
     return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to 
the documentation  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator, the sort implementation for Collections.sort(list, comparator) is mergeSort.

Given the result produced by mergeSort is ascending (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), the sort order of Collections.sort(list, comparator) is ascending.

That is to say if the comparator decides that element A is smaller than element B. In the sorted list, element A will be located at a smaller index than element B.