# What does 'Collections.sort(intervals, new Comparator<Interval>() { [...]' mean?

Tags: java, sorting

I came across a method that merges overlapping intervals. It has one part that I don't understand:

```
Collections.sort(intervals, new Comparator<Interval>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Interval i1, Interval i2) {
        return Integer.compare(i1.start, i2.start);
    }
});
```

What exactly is it doing and returning?

Comment: Are you asking to explain you the Collections.sort part, or to explain you how the algorithm works?

Comment: You seem to not know about anonymous inner classes. Read about them here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: @MarcinJedynak Just asking for explanation on the Colections.sort part

Comment: That sorts intervals by ascending starting point.

Comment: @assylias so say for example it was `{ {6,8}, {1,9}, {2,4}, {4,7} }`, would `{1,9}` come first, then `{2,4}` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

**What does it do:**
The Collections class in java has a method with the signature 
`sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`.

The first parameter is the list you want to sort the second is a Comparator.

```
new Comparator<Interval>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Interval i1, Interval i2) {
            return Integer.compare(i1.start, i2.start);
        }
    }
```

This is a short way([inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)) else you would need to write your own class which implements Comparator.

In short this could return `-1, 0, +1`

You can decide when to return which value.

In this case you call `Integer.compare` which compares like this  `-1 (i1 < i2) | 0 (i1==i2) | +1 (i1>i2)`.

Collection.sort uses this information to sort your list and it actually returns nothing.

Example for [Comparators](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/)

**EDIT :** The order would be { (1,9),(2,4),(4,7),(6,8) } as you compare the start of `I1` and `I2`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17641920/whats-the-sort-order-of-javas-collections-sortlist-comparator-small-to-big) accepted answer maybe is of interest.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, so in this case: `{ {6,8}, {1,9}, {2,4}, {4,7} }`, how would it be sorted? If it is like {start,end}?

Comment: @Nordiii So it only sorts when the `Integer.compare` returns +1? And in the case of returning `-1` and `0`, it does not do anything?

Comment: @Nordiii What if it returns like `return i1.start-i2.start;`, what would that mean?

Comment: @JoKo No  .sort() orders the elements when `Integer.compare returns -1` it knows `i1` is smaller than `i2` which means `i1` will come before `i2` in case it `returns 0` the order wouldn't be changed as they are equals when it `returns 1 sort()` knows that `i1` is greater than `i2` and therefore `i2` has to come before `i1`

Comment: @JoKo `return i1.start-i2.start` would probably work as compare is described like this `Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.`

Comment: @Nordiii Gotcha so it is just like the `Integer.compare()`? Just curious as to why the `-` sign.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128981/discussion-between-nordiii-and-jo-ko).